# Haskell Error for "foldl1 (\a b -> (snd a + snd b)) [(1,2), (3,4)]

Tags: haskell

Why doesn't this work?

```
Prelude> foldl1 (\a b -> ((snd a) + (snd b))) [(1,2),(3,4)]

<interactive>:1:17:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b = (a, b)
      Expected type: (a, b)
      Inferred type: b
    In the expression: ((snd a) + (snd b))
    In the first argument of `foldl1', namely
        `(\ a b -> ((snd a) + (snd b)))'
```

Answer (score 12):

`foldl1`'s function argument must have the type `a -> a -> a`, i.e. the 2 input arguments and the return value must have the same type. In your expression, that function is expected to return a 2-tuple `Num b => (a, b)`, not a pure number `Num b => b`, thus the "occurs check".

You could use `foldl` and provide an initial value, e.g.

```
foldl (\acc elm -> acc + snd elm) 0 [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

or use the existing functions

```
(sum . map snd) [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you provide to `foldl1` must return a value of the same type that is in your array.

Your array contains tuples of type `(Number, Number)`, but you are returning something of type `Number`.

If you want to return a Number in this case, you must use `foldl` rather than `foldl1` and writewrite this slightly (like KennyTM wrote above :D)